# How to set up wireshark to run without root on Debian?

Tags: debian, wireshark

I'm trying to use `wireshark` on a Debian machine, but when I run it with my non-root user account, it doesn't detect any network interface.

I also tried running wireshark as root, but wireshark tells me this method is insecure.

I also read the FAQ and found "read the file on /usr/shared/wireshark-common/README.Debian file" - I did read that file, but I still don't know what I'm supposed to do.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> By installing Wireshark packages non-root users won't gain rights automatically to capture packets.

You need `root` privileges to capture traffic with Wireshark (or `dumpcap`, for that matter). According to the manual you mentioned, it should be possible to add your user to the `wireshark` group though:

```
useradd -G wireshark your-user-name
```

Don't know if that alone will work though. Here's also [a guide from Wireshark Blog that explains it](https://blog.wireshark.org/2010/02/running-wireshark-as-you/) a bit more:

```
sudo -s
groupadd -g wireshark
usermod -a -G wireshark your-user-name
chgrp wireshark /usr/bin/dumpcap
chmod 4750 /usr/bin/dumpcap
```

That being said, you can safely run Wireshark to inspect, edit or filter packet dumps without `root` privileges.

Comment: Thanks for the details=) Also, I learnt that I should reboot before going 'Y U NOT WORKING'. Now it works brilliantly!!!

Comment: That's perfect, glad I could help. Rebooting normally shouldn't be necessary, logging out and in should in most cases fix issues.

Answer (score 52):

The file is actually `/usr/share/doc/wireshark-common/README.Debian`.

What you need to do is:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common
```

Choose the "yes" option.

```
usermod -a -G wireshark your-user-name
```

Logout and log back in to pick up the new group membership and you can now run wireshark as a non-root user.

Comment: This should really be the accepted answer; using `dpkg-reconfigure wireshark` is the right way to set up the wireshark group on Debian systems.  Making dumpcap setuid (as in the accepted answer) is unnecessary, as the package scripts will set up the appropriate caps on the group.

Comment: I don't have enough points to add a comment but to save having to log off to update Group Membership : su - $USER wireshark&

Comment: @Stuart Better: Just type `newgrp wireshark` in your shell. If you are part of that group, the shell will pick up your new membership (on request).

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the Wireshark configuration during installation with `apt`.

When running `dpdg-reconfigure wireshark` or during installation, it asks `Should non-superusers be able to capture packets?`. Pressing the left arrow key will make yes(是) marked by red. However, pressing the right arrow key and having no(否) allows non-superusers to capture packets as shown in the image below.

[image: The image of non-superusers choice]