# Setup wireshark to run as non root not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: permissions, wireshark, dpkg

I am pretty new to wireshark and I read that wireshark shouldn't be run as root because of security issues.

Anyway I did the following as mentioned in several places such as this [post](https://superuser.com/a/489110/1079269):

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure wireshark-common 

sudo usermod -a -G wireshark $USER
```

Then I logged out and in again and used the newgrp command but I can not run wireshark as non root with enough privileges to sniff.

Also I could recognized that the groups command doesn't list wireshark but according to /etc/group my user is in the wireshark group.

Thanks in advance
Amit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that for Ubuntu 20.04 you need to reboot the computer. It worked for me.

Comment: That indeed solved my problem that time. However, since than I installed wireshark on another ubuntu 20.04 instance and tried newgrp again. It worked but I recognized that after I fire the newgrp command it took some minutes until I could actually see any change using the groups-command. Can not tell why.